# TF2 Model from Numpy Arrays

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, model, tensorflow2.0

I came across the problem to reproduce TF2. model from numpy arrays (bias matrix and weight matrix for each layer). To avoid confusion bias matrix for the consistency of the numpy file is the 2D matrix with one column. This post shows how I did it.

```
class NumpyInitializer(tf.keras.initializers.Initializer):
    # custom class converting numpy arrays to tf's initializers 
    # used to initialize both kernel and bias
    def __init__(self, array):
        # convert numpy array into tensor 
        self.array = tf.convert_to_tensor(array.tolist())
        
    def __call__(self, shape, dtype=None):
        # return tensor 
        return self.array 

def restore_model_from_numpy(directory):

    """
    Recreate model from the numpy files. 
    Numpy files in the directory are ordered by layers
    and bias numpy matrix comes before numpy weight matrix. 

    In example: 
        directory-
            - L1B.npy //numpy bias matrix for layer 1
            - L1W.npy //numpy weights matrix for layer 1
            - L2B.npy //numpy bias matrix for layer 2
            - L2W.npy //numpy weights matrix for layer 2

    Parameters: 
        directory - path to the directory with numpy files
    Return: 
        tf's model recreated from numpy files
    """


    def file_iterating(directory):
        """
        Iterate over directory and create 
        dictionary of layers number and it's structure

        layers[layer_number] = [numpy_bias_matrix, numpy_weight_matrix]
        """

        pathlist = Path(directory).rglob("*.npy") # list of numpy files
        layers = {} # initialize dictionary 
        index = 0
        for file in pathlist: # iterate over file in the directory 
            if index % 2 == 0:
                layers[int(index/2)] = [] # next layer - new key in dictionary
            layers[int(index/2)].append(np.load(file)) # add to dictionary bias or weight 
            index +=1
            print(file) # optional to show list of files we deal with 
        return layers # return dictionary 

    layers = file_iterating(directory) # get dictionary with model structure

    inputs = Input(shape = (np.shape(layers[0][1])[0])) # create first model input layer
    x = inputs 

    for key, value in layers.items(): # iterate over all levers in the layers dictionary
        bias_initializer = NumpyInitializer(layers[key][0][0]) # create bias initializer for key's layer 
        kernal_initializer = NumpyInitializer(layers[key][1]) # create weights initializer for key's layer 
        layer_size = np.shape(layers[key][0])[-1] # get the size of the layer

        new_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense( # initialize new Dense layer
            units = layer_size, 
            kernel_initializer=kernal_initializer, 
            bias_initializer = bias_initializer,
            activation="tanh")
        x = new_layer(x) # stack layer at the top of the previous layer
        
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, x) # create tf's model based on the stacked layers 
    model.compile() # compile model 

    return model # return compiled model
```

In my directory, I had 4 numpy files (layer 1 - L1 and layer 2 - L2):

```
100_5_25_1Knapsack_Layer1\100_5_25_1Knapsack\L1B.npy , shape:  (1, 80)
100_5_25_1Knapsack_Layer1\100_5_25_1Knapsack\L1W.npy , shape:  (100, 80)
100_5_25_1Knapsack_Layer1\100_5_25_1Knapsack\L2B.npy , shape:  (1, 100)
100_5_25_1Knapsack_Layer1\100_5_25_1Knapsack\L2W.npy , shape:  (80, 100)
```

Calling the function result in:

```
m = restore_model_from_numpy(my_numpy_files_directory)
m.summary()

Model: "model_592"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_312 (InputLayer)       [(None, 100)]             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_137 (Dense)            (None, 80)                8080      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_138 (Dense)            (None, 100)               8100      
=================================================================
Total params: 16,180
Trainable params: 16,180
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

I hope that this post will be helpful to anyone as it's my first one.

Happy coding :D

Comment: You should replace the question in a question and answer format instead of the article format. Split the question in the question part and an answer part, answer your question and accept it. Give more details in the question part such why is this difficult or what can cause errors and make sure it is not a duplicate of other question.

Comment: Thank you for your post. As Sajan points suggests, please edit it to be a question and then add the solution as an answer, see [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) That will make it easier for people to find it and understand that what you are posting is a solution. For example, you can post something like "How do I build a Keras model from NumPy array files?", with a text like "I have a dir with NumPy array files like `bias1.npy`, `kernel1.npy`, `bias2.npy`, etc. How can I build a Keras model that uses those arrays as weights?"

Comment: Thank you. I have already changed it. Correct post can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63304056/how-do-i-build-a-tfmodel-from-numpy-array-files/63304057#63304057

Answer (score 0):

@Filip Kubacki, thank you for your solution. For the benefit of community i am providing solution here (answer section) to **Build Tensorflow model from NumPy array (i.e weights and biases) files**

```
class NumpyInitializer(tf.keras.initializers.Initializer):
    # custom class converting numpy arrays to tf's initializers 
    # used to initialize both kernel and bias
    def __init__(self, array):
        # convert numpy array into tensor 
        self.array = tf.convert_to_tensor(array.tolist())
        
    def __call__(self, shape, dtype=None):
        # return tensor 
        return self.array 

def restore_model_from_numpy(directory):

    """
    Recreate model from the numpy files. 
    Numpy files in the directory are ordered by layers
    and bias numpy matrix comes before numpy weight matrix. 

    In example: 
        directory-
            - L1B.npy //numpy bias matrix for layer 1
            - L1W.npy //numpy weights matrix for layer 1
            - L2B.npy //numpy bias matrix for layer 2
            - L2W.npy //numpy weights matrix for layer 2

    Parameters: 
        directory - path to the directory with numpy files
    Return: 
        tf's model recreated from numpy files
    """


    def file_iterating(directory):
        """
        Iterate over directory and create 
        dictionary of layers number and it's structure

        layers[layer_number] = [numpy_bias_matrix, numpy_weight_matrix]
        """

        pathlist = Path(directory).rglob("*.npy") # list of numpy files
        layers = {} # initialize dictionary 
        index = 0
        for file in pathlist: # iterate over file in the directory 
            if index % 2 == 0:
                layers[int(index/2)] = [] # next layer - new key in dictionary
            layers[int(index/2)].append(np.load(file)) # add to dictionary bias or weight 
            index +=1
            print(file) # optional to show list of files we deal with 
        return layers # return dictionary 

    layers = file_iterating(directory) # get dictionary with model structure

    inputs = Input(shape = (np.shape(layers[0][1])[0])) # create first model input layer
    x = inputs 

    for key, value in layers.items(): # iterate over all levers in the layers dictionary
        bias_initializer = NumpyInitializer(layers[key][0][0]) # create bias initializer for key's layer 
        kernal_initializer = NumpyInitializer(layers[key][1]) # create weights initializer for key's layer 
        layer_size = np.shape(layers[key][0])[-1] # get the size of the layer

        new_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense( # initialize new Dense layer
            units = layer_size, 
            kernel_initializer=kernal_initializer, 
            bias_initializer = bias_initializer,
            activation="tanh")
        x = new_layer(x) # stack layer at the top of the previous layer
        
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, x) # create tf's model based on the stacked layers 
    model.compile() # compile model 

    return model # return compiled model
```

In my directory, I had 4 numpy files (layer 1 - L1 and layer 2 - L2):

```
100_5_25_1Knapsack_Layer1\100_5_25_1Knapsack\L1B.npy , shape:  (1, 80)
100_5_25_1Knapsack_Layer1\100_5_25_1Knapsack\L1W.npy , shape:  (100, 80)
100_5_25_1Knapsack_Layer1\100_5_25_1Knapsack\L2B.npy , shape:  (1, 100)
100_5_25_1Knapsack_Layer1\100_5_25_1Knapsack\L2W.npy , shape:  (80, 100)
```

Calling the function result in:

```
m = restore_model_from_numpy(my_numpy_files_directory)
m.summary()

Model: "model_592"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_312 (InputLayer)       [(None, 100)]             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_137 (Dense)            (None, 80)                8080      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_138 (Dense)            (None, 100)               8100      
=================================================================
Total params: 16,180
Trainable params: 16,180
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```